# VBA scraped output to different rows Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am new to writing in VBA. I have been trying to scrape a website for data on ships.
So I wrote (well mostly copied) some script, I have gotten to the point that I can print the right results in the Immediate window, but not to excel. I wish to print the same results in Excel. I feel like the answer is nearby but I have been struggling and can't get it to work.

Script:

```
Sub Scrape()
'Get ship info

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLSCRAPE As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLSCR As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:5081/mmsi:230352000/vessel:MARJATTA"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to StackOverflow ..."

DoEvents

Loop

Set html = ie.document

Set HTMLSCRAPE = html.getElementsByTagName("div")


i = 0
For Each HTMLSCR In HTMLSCRAPE
   Debug.Print HTMLSCR.className, HTMLSCR.tagName, HTMLSCR.ID, HTMLSCR.innerText
Next HTMLSCR




Set ie = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

And the outputs in immediate window are :

```
ATD: 2020-01-22 09:34 LT (UTC +1)

ETA: 2020-01-24 01:30 LT (UTC +1)





PAST TRACK


ROUTE FORECAST

Reported ETA: 2020-01-24 01:30 LT (UTC +1)

Calculated ETA: ••••••••••


Calculated ETA at: ••••••••••


Predictive ETD: ••••••••••


Reported Destination: SEHEL


Distance Travelled: ••••••••••


Distance to Go: ••••••••••


Total Voyage Distance: ••••••••••


Time to Destination: ••••••••••



Draught (Reported/Max): 6.8 m / ••••••••••


Load Condition: ••••••••••


Speed recorded (Max / Average): 19 knots / 18.7 knots



VOYAGE TIMELINEPOSITION HISTORY

Reported Destination and ETA Received 2020-01-22 14:40 UTC

UNLOCK VOYAGE INFORMATION







Summary







Where is the ship?

General Cargo MARJATTA is currently located at UKC - North Sea at position 54° 46' 17.328" N, 5° 48' 27.821" E as reported by MarineTraffic Terrestrial Automatic Identification System on 2020-01-22 21:15 UTC (39 minutes ago)

The wind in this area at that time blows from West direction at force 2 Beaufort.

 

Where is this vessel going to?

The vessel departed from ROTTERDAM BOTLEK, NL on 2020-01-22 09:34 LT (UTC +1) and is currently sailing at 14.7 knots with Northeast direction heading to HELSINGBORG, SE with reported Estimated Time of Arrival at 2020-01-24 01:30 LT (UTC +1) local time (in 1 day, 2 hours )


 

What kind of ship is this?

MARJATTA (IMO: 9126247) is a General Cargo that was built in 1996 (24 years ago) and is sailing under the flag of Finland.

It’s carrying capacity is 6410 t DWT and her current draught is reported to be 6.8 meters. Her length overall (LOA) is 119.84 meters and her width is 17.9 meters.















Latest Position









Position Received: 2020-01-22 21:15 UTC
39 minutes ago

Vessel's Local Time: 
2020-01-22 21:15 LT UTC

Area: UKC - North Sea

Current Port: -

Latitude / Longitude: 54.77148° / 5.807728°

Status: Underway using Engine

Speed/Course: 14.7 kn / 33 °

AIS Source: 2701 Esvagt Alpha

NEARBY VESSELS


SHOW ON LIVE MAP



Weather





Wind: 4 knots

Wind direction: W (282°)

Air Temperature: 9°C
              DIV           wootric-area  
jss4          DIV                         









TermsPrivacyUser AgreementAbout
English (EN)MarineTraffic BlogHelp Centre
© Copyright 2007 - 2020 MarineTraffic.com
jss5          DIV                         








TermsPrivacyUser AgreementAbout
English (EN)MarineTraffic BlogHelp Centre
© Copyright 2007 - 2020 MarineTraffic.com
jss6          DIV                         







TermsPrivacyUser AgreementAbout
English (EN)MarineTraffic BlogHelp Centre
              DIV                         
jss8          DIV                         TermsPrivacyUser AgreementAbout
English (EN)MarineTraffic BlogHelp Centre
jss79         DIV                         TermsPrivacyUser AgreementAbout
jss13         DIV                         © Copyright 2007 - 2020 MarineTraffic.com
              DIV           MTLoader-1    
              DIV                         
              DIV                         
              DIV
```

How do I get this same output to excel in different rows?

## EDIT : everytime I run this script the results seems to differ.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to start pasting in `A1`:

```
Dim i as Long
i = 1
For Each HTMLSCR In HTMLSCRAPE
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1).Value = _
      HTMLSCR.className & "," & HTMLSCR.tagName & "," & HTMLSCR.ID & "," & HTMLSCR.innerText
   i = i + 1
Next HTMLSCR
```

Also, this assumes you can print the HTML info directly.

Comment: Hi, this loop doesn't seem to return the same output.. It doesn't return any content on the page.. Could you explain to me why the Debug.Print does this and the for loop doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments:

```
Sub Scrape()
'Get ship info

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Not needed
Dim HTMLSCRAPE As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLSCR As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim i As Long

  Set ie = New InternetExplorer
  ie.Visible = False
  ie.navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:5081/mmsi:230352000/vessel:MARJATTA"
  Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    'Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to StackOverflow ..." 'Not needed(?) Already not at all in the loop
    DoEvents
  Loop

  'Set html = ie.document 'Not needed

  Set HTMLSCRAPE = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

  'Headline in the first row
  Cells(1, 1).Value = "Class Name"
  Cells(1, 2).Value = "Tag Name"
  Cells(1, 3).Value = "ID"
  Cells(1, 4).Value = "Inner Text"
  'Freeze first line
  ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 0
  ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
  ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

  i = 2 'I use this variable for first row of dynamic data in the table
  For Each HTMLSCR In HTMLSCRAPE
    'Debug.Print HTMLSCR.className, HTMLSCR.tagName, HTMLSCR.ID, HTMLSCR.innerText
    '
    'Output the same values in the Excel spreadsheet from which you start the macro
    '(But I think, it's not realy what you want(?) Because it's EVERY div tag. Nobody needs every div tag in a document)
    'Please tell us ... Which values do you need?
    'Here come every div tags CSS class name if available [why?], tag name (div? ;-) [why?], id if available [why?] and innerText [which values you need?]
    Cells(i, 1).Value = HTMLSCR.className
    Cells(i, 2).Value = HTMLSCR.tagName
    Cells(i, 3).Value = HTMLSCR.ID
    Cells(i, 4).Value = HTMLSCR.innerText 'Makes the whole  table unreadable. I think you need one value of some lines
    i = i + 1
  Next HTMLSCR

  'Make the Table more readable by autofit rows and columns
  Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

  ie.Quit 'Exit IE (realy needed)
  Set ie = Nothing          'If clean up objects than everyone (Not really necessary, but consistent)
  Set HTMLSCRAPE = Nothing  'If clean up objects than everyone (Not really necessary, but consistent)
  Set HTMLSCR = Nothing     'If clean up objects than everyone (Not really necessary, but consistent)
  'Application.StatusBar = "" 'Not needed (?)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, This doesn't return the same results though as the `Debug.Print` and thats what I don't understand. Specifically I have been looking for the summary info about the ships.  I've gotten those results in the Debug Print but not in any of the loops.